# Import FullPage.js in Sage 9

Tags: javascript, npm, wordpress-theming, yarnpkg, roots-sage

I am trying to import Fullpage.js in my Sage theme.
I installed FullPageScroll with:

```
npm install fullpage.js
```

added the following code: scripts/main.js:

```
// import external dependencies
import 'jquery';
import 'fullpage.js/vendors/scrolloverflow.js';
import 'fullpage.js/dist/fullpage.js';
```

and: scripts/routes/home.js:

```
// Initializing it
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  //options here
  autoScrolling: true,

  //Navigation
  navigation: true,
  navigationPosition: 'left',
});

//methods
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
```

But still got this error (I followed the instruction documented in Sage book chapter 6.6):

> Uncaught TypeError: fullpage is not a constructor

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.